# Struts 1.x taglibs compatibility issues with jstl tags

Tags: java, jstl, wildfly, struts, taglib

I decided to post this question after 3,5 weeks of blocking and i'm really in need of someone's help.

The problem is with the compatibility and coherence of different taglibs, for budget reason we couldn't migrate the IHM and Web framework of the application which is **struts 1.2**

The problem after my analysis results in incompatibility between **struts-nested** taglib with it's possible values and **jstl** tags value.

for example :

The following code doesn't work

```
            <nested:iterate property="listeSupportsStructuresPlPg">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${listeSupportsStructuresPlPg.code eq 'PL' && !listeSupportsStructuresPlPg.testOfNajah}">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="niveauPLPG">
                                <b>Poche libre </b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </c:when>
              </c:choose>
        </nested:iterate>
```

As you can see the **c:when** test attribute uses the property **listeSupportsStructuresPlPg** provided by the **nested:iterate** tag, when i replace the **nested:iterate** with **c:forEach** it works just fine but it crashes later when i wanna do another thing + there are 100s occurences of such code and it will be almost impossible to resolve. it's a very difficult situation i'm facing these times, especially that i have tried everything possible to make this incompatible tags work with each other but no good results was obtained.

> Project Context: We were migrating from Web-Logic Server To WilfFly 10.0.0.FINAL, before Migration i'd like to say that this isssue never existed.

**Solutions i tried before posting this question**

> I replaced the local c.tld with

```
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

> I replaced nested:iterate with c:forEach but it didn't work
>
> I replaced strus-nested.tld with many definitions but it didn't work
>
> I upgraded the version from 1.2 to 1.3 until 1.x terminated
>
> I tried to do change the value of the conditions by evaluating booleans instead of lists but it worked only in some places and i couldn't find why.

that's all i can remember, but i can assure you that i tried a lot of possible fixes but no results.

Comment: did you try `<nested:iterate id="item" property="listeSupportsStructuresPlPg">` and `${item.code eq 'PL'...}`?

Comment: No it didn't work

Comment: "It didn't work" is not diagnostic. It's unclear what you're trying to do (e.g., no clue what you're trying to iterate over), unclear what didn't work with your attempts, etc.

Comment: Please use custum tld for this kind of code that will be good approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it after a deep analysis guy,

Here are the steps that i followed so i can make this page work

Step 1: **Changing the way we load the TLDs**

Previously they were loaded locally from WEB-INF folder, i changed it so it can be loaded directly from the appropriate jars.

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %> 
 <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-nested" prefix="nested" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/cgit.tld" prefix="cgit" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>
```

Step 2: **Dropping all local TLDs**

Step 3: **Struts framework version upgrade**

Previously they core version was at **1.2.8**, The current version is **1.3.10**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

and i changed a little bit the **nested:iterate** by adding the element **id** which represents the same thing as **var** represents in **c:forEach**

```
    <nested:iterate id="row" property="listeSupportsStructuresPlPg">
            <c:out value="${row.****}"/>
    </nested:iterate>
```

This way the **jstl c** tags can understand the **nested:iterate** property element.

Just for information, **u skip one if these steps, nothing works**

Thanks for those whom tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `c` tags don't know how to access the Struts value stack, so they don't know what `listeSupportsStructuresPlPg` is.  Use the struts equivalent of `<c:choose>`.  In Struts 2, this is `<s:if>`.  I'm not sure exactly what it is in Struts 1, but probably something similar.